# Why does my \includegraphics size not match the length of the coordinate system after setting the height and width?

Tags: includegraphics, coordinates

mycode is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[canvas is zy plane at x=0mm] (temp) at (0.0mm,0.0mm,0.0mm) {\includegraphics[width=80.0mm,height=80.0mm]{cats.jpg}};
\draw (0mm,0mm,0mm) -- (1mm,0mm,0mm);
\draw (0mm,0mm,0mm) -- (0mm,1mm,0mm);
\draw (0mm,0mm,0mm) -- (0mm,0mm,1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and it output like this:
[image]

As you can see, the width and height should be 80mm, but it seems like only less than 2mm.
the image is :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!

Comment: Welcome. // Thank you for positing code, which can compile. However, can you please remove all lines, which aren't necessary here to show your problem? Can you also provide the cats-image, please? Thank you // BTW, what's the size when you show it on othere axis? What's the separation inside the node?

Comment: if you can demonstrate the problem with `example-image` everyone has that so it is easier to test answers

Comment: You ask TikZ to transform your node (by using the `canvas …` key), thus it will get transformed accordingly. It was 80mmx80mm beforehand. Please don't use [canvas coordinates](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.2.1) (the ones with a unit, always 2d) in the *xyz* coordinate system (the ones without units, can be 2d or 3d). The `1mm` will be converted to 2.84526pt which then will be used in the *xyz* coordinate system as 2.84526. The 1mm has nothing to do anymore with the actual diagram since the 2.84526 are used as a factor for the *x*, *y* or *z* vector.

Comment: In other words, you can fix the problem by getting rid of `mm` everywhere except \includegraphics.